# Mongoose get newest four distinct items sold

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am having trouble getting my head around how to retrieve four newly sold items from the database. There is a schema called Order which has a field called item, which is just the item sold with this order. Currently I sort the order documents from newest to oldest, I do a limit for 4 orders, and retrieve the items associated with these 4 newest orders. 1 order has only 1 item.

However, items don't have to be unique. Maybe these 4 newest orders are all for 1 item. It would be stupid to have 4 exact items on the first page saying these four are the newly sold. I have considered using distinct(), aggregate, group, etc, but none of which seems to fit my goal. I really wanna avoid using brute force to search order 1 by 1 until I get 4 unique items.

Can anyone give me some hint as to how to achieve this?

```
Order{
    item: {type: ObjectId, ref: "Item"},
    date_added: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}

Item{
    name: {type: String},
    price: {type: Number}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this you could use if everything was in one collection:

```
db.Order.aggregate([
  {$sort: {_id: -1}},
  {$group: {
     _id: "$item",
     firstId: {$first: "$_id"}    
    }
  }, 
  {$sort: {firstId: -1}},
  { $limit: 4 }
])
```

---

After your question update this is not possible. So to replicate your example I created the following:

Collection: `order`

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25361a38f4fb1fc057bb95"), 
    "item" : ObjectId("5a2535d238f4fb1fc057bb92"), 
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T11:48:42.610+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25369a38f4fb1fc057bb9b"), 
    "item" : ObjectId("5a25367c38f4fb1fc057bb98"), 
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T11:50:50.569+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254de038f4fb1fc057bba9"), 
    "item" : ObjectId("5a254d7438f4fb1fc057bb9e"), 
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T13:30:08.148+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254e1f38f4fb1fc057bbb2"), 
    "item" : ObjectId("5a254d8938f4fb1fc057bba1"), 
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T13:31:38.038+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254e6438f4fb1fc057bbb5"), 
    "item" : ObjectId("5a254d9e38f4fb1fc057bba4"), 
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-12-04T13:32:20.244+0000")
}
```

Collection: `item`

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2535d238f4fb1fc057bb92"), 
    "name" : "mouse", 
    "price" : "50"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25367c38f4fb1fc057bb98"), 
    "name" : "keyboard", 
    "price" : "100"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254d7438f4fb1fc057bb9e"), 
    "name" : "monitor", 
    "price" : "500"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254d8938f4fb1fc057bba1"), 
    "name" : "mouse", 
    "price" : "15"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a254d9e38f4fb1fc057bba4"), 
    "name" : "headphones", 
    "price" : "110"
}
```

So based on what you described you can do this:

```
db.order.aggregate([

{$sort: {_id: -1}},
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "item",
       localField: "item",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "items"
     }
},
{ $unwind: "$items"},
{
  $group: 
  {
     _id: "$items.name",
     orderId: {$first: "$_id"},
     itemId: {$first: "$item"},
     date_added: {$first: "$date_added"},
     itemName: {$first: "$items.name"},
     itemPrice: {$first: "$items.price"},
  }
}, 
{$sort: {orderId: -1}},
{ $limit: 4 }
])
```

As I said it would be wise to use a `$match` before you do all that. Like this for example:

```
db.order.aggregate([
{ $match: {"date_added" : {$gte: ISODate("2017-12-04T11:48:43.610+0000")}}},
{$sort: {_id: -1}},
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "item",
       localField: "item",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "items"
     }
},
{ $unwind: "$items"},
{
  $group: 
  {
     _id: "$items.name",
     orderId: {$first: "$_id"},
     itemId: {$first: "$item"},
     date_added: {$first: "$date_added"},
     itemName: {$first: "$items.name"},
     itemPrice: {$first: "$items.price"},
  }
}, 
{$sort: {orderId: -1}},
{ $limit: 4 }
])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the advice! By the way, my item field is actually an _id that could be populated to a schema called Item. Since I cant populate while I do this, does it mean I have to search these 4 _ids manually after this operation?

Comment: Oh so you have two collections, with foreign key? If this is the case then you can  use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Can you explain it in your description?